# kaminari and order_by

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

So Im listing out all the members of my site and grouping them by name so that the list will be organized better. So in my view all my members are grouped by the first letter of their member name  like:

```
B

Bakedfish
Beercan Dan
Bigmike33x 

C

Cynicalassassin
ect..
```

Anyway, I also want to paginate this list but I cant add Kaminari's pagination arguments to my controller if Im using order because I get an undefined method error.

so this doesnt work:

```
@members = Member.all.group_by{|u| u.fullname[0].titleize}.page(params[:page]).per(18)
```

my view looks like this:

```
<div class="content">
  <%= paginate @members %>
</div>
    <% @members.keys.sort.each do |starting_letter| %>
            <h3>
            <%= link_to starting_letter, {:action => :browse, :controller =>:members, :letter => starting_letter } %>
</h3>
      <ol>
                <% @members[starting_letter].each do |member| %>
                    <li>
                        <% if member.is_artist? %>
                            <%= link_to member.full_name, member_path(member), :class=>"artist" %>
                        <% else %>
                            <%= link_to member.full_name, member_path(member) %>
                        <% end %>
                    </li>
                <% end %>
        </ol>
    <% end %>
```

Here is my error message:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `page' for #<Hash:0x007f78d4bf48f8>):
  app/controllers/members_controller.rb:10:in `index'
```

Comment: It would be better, if you write an error (message, line, etc.)

Comment: I've added the error message, the line in the controller its referencing is up there already.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Kaminari adds `page` method to `ActiveRecord::Relation` but `Member.all.group_by` returns hash. That is why you get this exception.

I'd suggest to perform grouping after pagination, e.g.:

```
@members = Member.order(:full_name).page(params[:page]).per(18).to_a.group_by { |u| u.fullname[0].upcase }
```

**UPDATE**

In order to use `paginate` helper you could assign 2 variables, e.g.:

```
@paginated_members = Member.order(:full_name).page(params[:page]).per(18)
@members = @paginated_members.to_a.group_by { |u| u.fullname[0].upcase }
```

And pass `@paginated_members` to the `paginate` helper.

Comment: Ahh ok cool well that error is resolved, but now the pagination helper isnt working, I get `undefined method `current_page'`  on the line `<%= paginate @members %>`