# Kaminari Not working due to group keyword

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, kaminari

```
@users = User.registred
        .includes(:items)
        .joins('LEFT OUTER JOIN items ON users.id=items.user_id')
        .group(User.column_names.collect do |c| "#{User.table_name}.#{c}" end.join(','))
        .order('CASE WHEN LENGTH(users.profile_picture) > 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END, followers_count DESC, bibbed_items_count DESC, SUM(items.user_likes_count) DESC, users.id')
```

where `registered = where("deactivated_at IS NULL AND last_sign_in_at IS NOT NULL")`

Kaminari not working with group clause. How to optimized group clause in this query ?

Comment: I _think_ this may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10758361/387135

Comment: I don't see where you are calling the `page` method...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed it using this:

```
@users = User.registred
        .includes(:items)
        .joins('LEFT OUTER JOIN items ON users.id=items.user_id')
        .group("users.id")
        .order('CASE WHEN LENGTH(users.profile_picture) > 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END, followers_count DESC, bibbed_items_count DESC, SUM(items.user_likes_count) DESC, users.id')

@users = @users.page(params[:page])
```

Answer (score 3):

Had the same issue, fixed it like you - by providing an appropiate `id` value in the `group` clause. However, apparently it doesn't need to replace your original group clause - just append an additional call:

```
@users = User.registred
    .includes(:items)
    .joins('LEFT OUTER JOIN items ON users.id=items.user_id')
    .group(User.column_names.collect do |c| "#{User.table_name}.#{c}" end.join(','))
    .order('CASE WHEN LENGTH(users.profile_picture) > 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END, followers_count DESC, bibbed_items_count DESC, SUM(items.user_likes_count) DESC, users.id')
    .group('users.id')
```

Comment: You do not need a new group clause. If you put the users.id at the end of the first group clause, it will work. Thanks for you answer, I just figure it out because of you.